# Converting batch output into String

Tags: sql, batch-file, scripting

I have written this simple script that converts the computer's date (format: MM/DD/YYYY) into  Sql periodId (YYYYMMDD).

```
@echo off set %mydate%=%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%
```

However, the output of %mydate% is numeric (int). How can I make it so that %mydate%'s output becomes a string?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What DBMS are yo uusing?

Comment: What is calling this batch file, and what is using the result and telling you that the 20140623 value is an int?

Comment: Hi. I am using Sql server 2008. And %Mydate% is used as a variable to pass the periodId for a daily DTS package.

Comment: How about (a 1 liner) this - `@set mydate='%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%'`

Comment: When I run the batch (which runs the associated packages) I get the following error: 
"Error:  -2147217913 (80040E07); Provider Error:  242 (F2)
   Error string:  The conversion of a varchar data type to a smalldatetime data
type resulted in an out-of-range value."

The reason for the error is that my DTS package takes only string parameters.

Comment: @AjVJsy When I apply your suggestion, the output comes as '20140623' (with the quotation marks).

Comment: It's difficult to say without knowing what exactly the SQL package is doing with the %MyDate% variable. This runs happily for me : `select convert(smalldatetime,'20140623')` so what exactly is the package doing with it?

Comment: @AjVJsy: Actually it worked for me as well after using " instead of '. THanks! One more question. What if I want to get the day prior through the code above. So basically today's date -1 day. I appreciate it a lot guys!